# Why is my area offset using the V.buffer tool

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am using QGIS V 3.2, and I am trying to use the `v.buffer GRASS TOOL` to create a 500 meters exclusion zone (Circle) around a point. After creating a `point shapefile` I then ran the `v.buffer tool` and set the parameters as seen in the screen shots. My map units are km, so if I want a 500m exclusion zone I would input *0.05* (however this doesn't work, so I input *0.005*. The outcome is seen in the final figure where not only is the exclusion zone off center from the brown point, it is also 575m. does anyone know how to A) correct the exclusion zone to not be offcenter and B), create an exclusion zone equal to 500m. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [EPSG:4230](http://epsg.io/4230) is in degrees not km.

Comment: You are using a projection (epsg 4230), that uses geographical coordinates (degrees). Convert your data to a projected coordinate system to use linear meseaurements

Comment: I have just changed the CRS to wgs84 (Which is what I require it in). this has solved the problem of my area being offset. if I run the V.buffer again will solve the issue of my exclusion area being the wrong size and correct itself to 500m?

Comment: You need to pick a projection that is in metres for this to work. Consider something like http://epsg.io/23038

Comment: I need to use the WGS84 CRS for the project I am working on. Is there any other way to calculate an accurate 500m zone. I have thought about using the _measuring tool_ to calculate 500m, then converted it into degrees, found the degrees and manually plugging that into v.buffer, would this be an accurate way?

Comment: You might read through this article.  It was written for ArcGIS but the information on geodesic versus planar buffers is one any buffering needs to address.  http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0111/geodesic.html.  Note you can create your buffer in a projection and then display the result in your project letting QGIS "reproject it on the fly" or you could reproject the resulting buffer  using the Reproject layer tool in Vector General.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, they have proven most useful

Comment: if you have solved your problem, please post (and accept) it as an answer